# On-Screen Keyboard Location settings

Tags: windows-10, on-screen-keyboard

Long time browser, first time asker.

So we have an environment, that we'd like to lock down to a specific setup. They have large tablet like devices in a clean-room.  They RDP to an EBR Workstation, and we'd like to make sure the keyboard is open, and docked to the bottom of the screen.  I have already set the RDP window to be scroll-less, and fixed to a location. The keyboard opens pre-login, and after login it is there in it's last known state, but i have been googling for a few days, and cannot find where these settings are stored for the osk.exe.  They have to be stored somewhere, as it has a memory of where it was last opened and what not.  Anyone have any ideas, or know if this is even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows 7, many OSK settings are stored in the registry, under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Osk`. I expect it is the same in Windows 10.

I find WindowHeight, WindowLeft, WindowTop, and WindowWidth, and they correspond to the location and size of the OSK window when it was last closed. I also find values corresponding to the settings under OSK's `Option` dialog.

(I don't see anything about docking to the bottom, but that might be because I'm looking at Windows 7.)

Edit: Yep, the settings are in the same place in Windows 10. And there is a `Dock` entry.

Comment: That looks like it!!! I will run some tests over the next few days. I can't believe i didn't look there. I had been all over the reg keys, but only with hints of people doing other things like turning it on/off or disabling it entirely. Which are in Ease of Access areas...